# Applescript - why can I not use classes which are dynamically assigned?

Tags: applescript

Why can't I do the bottom 2 programs, if I can do the top one in Applescript?

```
set _class to string
return ({"o", "k"} as string)
```

This works, but the bottom 2 don't.

```
set _class to string
return ({"o", "k"} as _class)
```

Or

```
set _class to string
return ({"o", "k"} as (class of "hello"))
```

The program doesn't let me compile neither of the bottom 2.

Comment: Are you trying to create a record type class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because classes are evaluated at compile time and therefore must be static.

Comment: Is there any way at all to get around this?

Comment: There is a way called "second level evaluation" but it's ugly and very slow

Comment: They're not classes. They're symbolic names, c.f. instances of Ruby's `Symbol` type. (AppleScript doesn't even have classes, just a handful of built-in datatypes, each of which includes a `class` property containing the _name_ of that type.) You can't parameterize the right-hand operand to AppleScript's `as` operator because AppleScript is poorly designed and mostly sucks. (Brilliant for sending Apple events, useless for doing anything else.)

Answer (score 0):

Since AppleScript's `as` operator is so crap, all you can really do is define your own handlers that perform the required conversions for you. (And since AS handlers aren't designed to be passed around as objects themselves, you need to wrap them in script objects as well. It's all very tedious.)

```
script StringCoercion
    on coerceValue(theValue)
        (* caution: to guarantee predictable behavior, always set
           TIDs to a known value before coercing an unknown value
           to a string, just in case that value is a list *)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        return theValue as string
    end
end

script ListCoercion
    on coerceValue(theValue)
        return theValue as list
    end
end

set _class to StringCoercion
return _class's coerceValue({"o", "k"})
--> "ok"
```

Or, if you don't need that much flexibility, just use a conditional block:

```
set _class to string
set theValue to {"o", "k"}

if _class is string then
    return theValue as string
else if _class is list then
    return theValue as list
else ...
```

Honestly, the more the more you think about these things, the more you realize just how poor AppleScript is for [i]everything[/i] that isn't automating applications. Unfortunately, the Apple-supplied alternatives to AS suck for automating applications, so it's pretty much Hobson's choice.

Honestly, best I can recommend is to make your AS code as simple, boring, and not-clever as you can, and hopefully it's less likely to blow up.